# Tab is not working in the expected way -Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, nav, mat-tab

I am just trying to learn angular. I am using angular 8 and material latest.I am sharing my **dashboard.components.html**

```
<div><nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/admin']">Admin</a>
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/order']">Orders</a>
    </nav></div>
  <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
```

**AppRoutingModule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent} from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { OrdersComponent} from './components/orders/orders.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent 
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
  {path: 'order', component: OrdersComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The problem here is when I click on the tab page is getting loaded but tab screen disappears. I want Nab bar tab should be present there all the time. Just below of that tab nav bar the page should get loaded. Here thats not happening. All the time I have to click back button. Can any one tell me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify children routes for 'dashboard' path.  So, your app will load DashboardComponent (with tabs content) and router-outlet (selected child)

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent 
        children: [
         {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
         {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
         {path: 'order', component: OrdersComponent}
        ]
      },
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
   ];
```

Comment: Any way to set default active path as home ? , I did it using  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'} and it worked. But default the tab is not active though it shows the page.

Comment: try redirectTo dashboard/home

Comment: No. It is not working. There should be something in the tag itself to set the default tab selected.

Comment: I will post another question if it is not working after few trail.